# EF core. will it erase existing tables in a database that are " not " part of the DbContext class?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Will using entity framework core code as below erase existing tables in the database that are " not " included part of the DbContext class?

This is all the code i have. No Db initializers. No migrations enabled.

```
public class EmailServiceDbContext : DbContext
{
    public EmailServiceDbContext(DbContextOptions options):base(options)
    {
        ;
    }
    public DbSet<CourierReportsDeliveriesView> CourierReportsDeliveriesView { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And the configuration:

```
// Add DbContext
services.AddDbContext<EmailServiceDbContext>(options => options
    .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnectionString")));
```

Comment: I don't think so...I think it will probably map this entity created/mapped and the application won`t have access to the existing tables

Comment: No, it won't. There are no initializers like DropCreateIfModelChanges in core. You create the database through migrations or Database.EnsureCreated. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro)